# How come rebasing to a branch that has rebased introduces merge conflicts and seems to erase my current changes?

Tags: git, rebase, branching-and-merging

I am working with some others in a git repository, where a large change was made on `branch a`. The branch was basically finished and was waiting for approval, so when I started implementing my new feature I branched off it rather than `master`. I am working on `branch b`. There were some minor changes to `branch a` that I moved into `branch b` with a merge (though in retrospect I should have rebased).

After that, a change in `branch c` was merged into `master`. `branch b` was rebased to `master`.

I want to rebase to `branch a` to get these changes in my branch also, but when I do so I get several confusing conflicts in files I haven't touched. Where I have changed the files, what I see in in the conflict does not reflect my changes. Instead, it seems as though I am resolving `branch a` and `master`, only `branch a` is labelled as HEAD and `master` as `branch a`. I'm confused.

How did this happen, and what can I best do?

If I merge again rather than rebasing I do see my own changes - though there are still conflicts in files I haven't changed, and the conflicts span many lines that haven't been touched on `branch a` since I branched off it. I can to resolve this alright - but I was hoping not to repeat my earlier mistake.

I was expecting just to need to resolve the 3-4 lines that changed on `branch c` in the files I modified.

Comment: What a Mess. I quite frankly was not able to follow your instructions.... but my best advice would be: checkout to the point where you want feature-b (_your_ branch) to start. Use `--detach` when checking out. Then **cherry-pick** the revisions that make up real work on your feature (no merges). This way your are _cleaning up_ your branch. If you like the end result, move your feature-b branch and check it out (`git branch -f featyre-b; git checkout feature-b`)... and be more careful next time.

Answer (score 1):

Fundamentally, these problems occur because—well, *primarily* because—rebase works 
by *copying* commits.  The questions is which commits get copied—*what*, *where*, *when*, and *why*: four of the [five Ws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Five_Ws).  *Who* may also be interesting, and for the sixth factor, *how* ... well, we'll see that in a moment.

Fixing the mess is most likely just a matter of copying *just the right commits* now, which you might be able to do with `git rebase`, or which may be easier with `git cherry-pick`.

#### Background

To understand this properly, you need to have a good grasp of precisely what a commit is, how commits get found, and how commits get copied.  For a proper in-depth explanation of how commits get found, see [Think Like (a) Git](http://think-like-a-git.net/), but we'll touch on it lightly here.

What a commit *is* comes in two parts: data—a snapshot of your source—and metadata, such as your name and email address and other information *about* the commit:

- The snapshot is just that: a complete copy of *every* source file, however it stands at the time you make the commit.  The snapshot is actually made from the *index*, rather than from the source you can see, and this is why you keep having to `git add` files over and over again: `git add somefile` really means *copy file `somefile` from the version I can see and work with, replacing whatever copy may be in the index now with this improved one.*  Running `git commit` snapshots the index copy.
- The metadata includes the other stuff that `git log` can show: your name and email address (from your configured `user.name` and `user.email`); the date-and-time-stamp of when you made the commit; and most important to humans, but unimportant to Git, the *reason* you made the commit: the log message.  But it also includes one more item—or sometimes, multiple items—that are crucially important to Git: the *hash ID* of each of the *parent* commits of this new commit.

Every commit is uniquely identified by its hash ID.  No two commits can ever share a hash ID.  The hash ID appears to be completely random, but in fact it's completely *non*-random: it's a cryptographic checksum of the contents of the commit, including the source snapshot, your name and email, the date and time—the time helps makes the commit unique even if you sneakily commit the *same code* twice, using the same name and email and log message—and (somehow, but this isn't hard after all) the hash ID(s) of the same parent(s) as well.

Because hash IDs are cryptographic checksums, neither you nor anyone else—not even Git—can change *anything* about a commit once it's committed.  If you take an existing commit, extract it, fiddle with it at all, and make a new commit, then either you've preserved every single bit of the original commit and hence haven't changed it and it's still just the original commit, or, you get a new and different commit with a completely different hash ID.  What this means is that in a sense, the hash ID **is** the commit.

Meanwhile, each commit stores the hash ID of its parent(s).  With any simple linear chain of commits, this means we can start with the *last* commit and use it to find each earlier commit.  By representing commits as single uppercase letters instead of real hash IDs, we can draw this as:

```
... <-F <-G <-H
```

where `H` is the hash ID of the *last* commit in some branch.  Moreover, this works for multiple branches as well: we just need to save, somewhere, the hash ID of *each* final commit:

```
...--F--G--H   <-- somehow remember H
         \
          I--J   <-- somehow remember J
```

This is where Git's branch names come in.  **What a branch name does is remember the hash ID of one commit.**  If `master` remembers `H` and `dev` remembers `J`, then we have some series of shared commits on *both* branches—everything through commit `G` is shared—and one commit private to `master` and two private to `dev`.

#### Copying one commit with `git cherry-pick`

If a commit is a snapshot—and it is—how can `git log` or `git show` *show* it as a diff?  How can you copy one commit to a new, slightly different commit?  The answer lies in those same parent connections.

Suppose that commit `J` is actually an important bug fix, having nothing to do with the development going on on `dev`.  We'd like to copy the fix in `J` into `master` to make a new commit `K`, giving us:

```
...--F--G--H--K   <-- master
         \
          I--J   <-- dev
```

What we need Git to do is to take the snapshots in `I` and `J` and compare them to each other.  Whatever *changed* from `I` to `J`, that's the bug-fix we need to apply to `H`.

The `git cherry-pick` command does this.  It does this using Git's internal *merge machinery* so that any *other* differences between `I` and `H` can be maintained correctly, but we'll ignore the details here: in simple cases, the merge has no complicated work to do, and we can just imagine that Git just applies the `I`-vs-`J` changes to `H` to produce the copy of `J` that we'll call `K`.

That gives us just what we wanted: `K` and `J` do the same *thing*, so `K` is sort of a copy of `J`, but they do it to a different *starting point*, so `K`'s parent is `H` (on `master`) and `K` itself can be safely kept only on `master`.  Because `K` is a copy of `J`, Git will by default use the same author and log message and even the same time-stamp.  You, and now, are the *committer* of new copy `K`, but whoever made `J` is the *author*.  Of course, `J` and `K` have different *hash IDs*—they're different commits—but `K` is a copy of `J`.

#### Rebase is just an en-masse copy

Suppose we start instead with this:

```
...--F--G--H   <-- master
      \
       I--J--K   <-- dev
```

This time there are no important bug fixes.  We'd just like to take the three commits that are on `dev` and make them start from `H`, rather than from `F`.

What we can do at this point is create a *new* `dev2` branch, pointing to commit `H`, like this:

```
$ git checkout -b dev2 master
```

giving:

```
...--F--G--H   <-- master, dev2 (HEAD)
      \
       I--J--K   <-- dev
```

The special name `HEAD` tells us (and Git) which branch name gets updated as we go, so `HEAD` is attached to our new `dev2`.

Now we can, one at a time, copy commit `I`, then `J`, then `K`.  Let's call the copies `I'`, `J'`, and `K'` this time:

```
             I'-J'-K'   <-- dev2 (HEAD)
            /
...--F--G--H   <-- master
      \
       I--J--K   <-- dev
```

Now let's *delete* the name `dev` entirely:

```
$ git branch -D dev

             I'-J'-K'   <-- dev2 (HEAD)
            /
...--F--G--H   <-- master
      \
       I--J--K   ???
```

and then *rename* `dev2` to `dev`:

```
$ git branch -m dev2 dev

             I'-J'-K'   <-- dev (HEAD)
            /
...--F--G--H   <-- master
```

With no name by which to find them, original commits `I-J-K` seem to be gone.  Since the name by which we find the three *new* commits is `dev`, it *seems* as though we have magically replaced the original three commits.  We haven't—the original three are actually still in the repository, and will normally remain there for a while in case we change our minds and want them back.  But normal Git commands won't *see* them.  They're hidden away, so that we only see the new and improved `dev` branch.

This—copying commits, as if by `git cherry-pick`, and then re-shuffling branch names—is what `git rebase` does.  But suppose, unbeknownst to whoever is doing this reshuffling of `dev`, *you*, in *your* Git repository, have made several more commits that depend on commit `K`?  If you were to grab their stuff while they have a `dev2`, you would see this:

```
             I'-J'-K'   <-- origin/dev2
            /
...--F--G--H   <-- master, origin/master
      \
       I--J--K   <-- dev, origin/dev
              \
               L--M--N   <-- branch-b
```

If you wait until they've replaced their `dev`—and in general, you *have* to—then your own repository gets updated like this:

```
             I'-J'-K'   <-- origin/dev
            /
...--F--G--H   <-- master, origin/master
      \
       I--J--K   <-- dev
              \
               L--M--N   <-- branch-b
```

Now suppose you either delete your `dev`, or—more likely—update it to match theirs.  What you see in your repository is:

```
             I'-J'-K'   <-- dev, origin/dev
            /
...--F--G--H   <-- master, origin/master
      \
       I--J--K--L--M--N   <-- branch-b
```

This means that you now have not three but *six* commits on your `branch-b` that they—the people running the `origin/*` names—*don't* have.

As far as Git is concerned, *all six commits*, `I-J-K-L-M-N`, are *your* commits.

If you rebase your `branch-b` onto your/their `master` *right now*, Git will try to copy *all six* commits.  If you rebase onto their `origin/dev`, something more interesting happens, which we'll come back to in a moment.

Over time, they might merge their work into `master`, and/or you might merge their work into yours.  Here's one potential graph, if they've merged their `K'` into their `master` (your `origin/master` and your now-updated `master`) and then you merged that `O` commit into your `branch-b` to produce merge `P`:

```
             I'--J'--K'   <-- dev, origin/dev
            /         \
...--F--G--H-----------O   <-- master, origin/master
      \                 \
       I--J--K--L--M--N--P   <-- branch-b
```

#### Whenever you rebase, your Git enumerates commits to copy

When you run `git rebase target`, your Git has to figure out which commits to copy.  The list of commits to copy starts with all commits *reachable from* your current branch—hence, commits `I-J-K-L-M-N-P` but also `F-G-H-...-O-P` due to the fact that `P` is a merge commit.  Here, again, I suggest working through [Think Like (a) Git](http://think-like-a-git.net/).

From this big list of all reachable commits, Git immediately subtracts all commits reachable from the target.  So if you chose, say, `dev` as your target, Git would eliminate commits `F-G-H-I'-J'-K'`.  If you chose `master`, Git would eliminate `F-G-H-I'-J'-K'-O`.  These are obvious to eliminate from the list because they're already there in the target.

Git also omits any *merge* commits, just automatically.  So that knocks out `O` and `P`.  Merge commits literally cannot be copied: copying a commit requires comparing it to its (single) parent, and merge commits have two parents.  There's no way for Git to know which parent to use, so it just doesn't copy them.

But that still leaves `I-J-K-L-M-N` as the list of commits to (maybe) copy.  This is where Git's idea of how to identify an already-copied commit comes in.

For each commit that's in the upstream "already there, don't copy" list—which includes `I'-J'-K'`—Git computes a *patch ID*, using the `git patch-id` program.  This essentially reduces each commit to an approximation of the change from the parent of that commit, to that commit.  That is, Git finds the same set of changes that `git cherry-pick` would copy, and computes a hash ID from those changes.

Then, Git computes patch-IDs for all of *your* commits `I-J-K-L-M-N`.  If any of those patch-IDs match the patch-IDs for the upstream commits, Git knocks those commits out.  **In many cases, this completely rescues your rebase and everything just works.**  Your original `I-J-K` commits—well, yours *now*, even though they weren't yours originally—are left over in your branch because they copied theirs to `I'-J'-K'` and then abandoned their `I-J-K`, but your `branch-b` retained them even though they *thought* they had left `I-J-K` behind forever.  But if your `I-J-K` have patch-IDs that match their `I'-J'-K'`, your rebase will work well.

If their patch-IDs *don't* match, though, *now* you have a problem.  Git can't automatically exclude the copied commits.  The nearly-but-not-exactly-the-same commits *will* clash when Git goes to apply them at their new place for the rebase.  These will be files you never touched, but whose changes you inherited in the preserved commits that they—whoever "they" are—*thought* they had successfully abandoned.  You're bringing back their work as your own, even though it's not something you wanted.

#### What you'll need to do to recover

The way to recover from all of this is to figure out which commits *should* get copied.  If you're lucky, they may all be in a neat simple row.  In this case you can use `git rebase --onto` to split the job into two parts.  Normally you run:

```
git rebase <target>
```

and *`target`* specifies both the place to put the copies, and the set of commits to *avoid* copying.  But you can run:

```
git rebase --onto <target> <dontcopy>
```

and now *`target`* *only* specifies where to put the copies; the *`dontcopy`* argument tells Git what not to copy.  Those same [reachability rules from Think Like (a) Git](http://think-like-a-git.net/) determine which commits will and won't be put in the "maybe copy" list.  Rebase will then throw out all merges and all same-patch-ID commits too, and copy whatever remains.

If you're *not* lucky, the set of commits to copy will be sprinkled about, hither and yon.  You'll have to create a new temporary branch, or use "detached HEAD" mode, and run a series of `git cherry-pick` commands to copy the commits that *should* get copied, the ones that are truly yours.

#### Merging avoids this problem because merging doesn't copy commits

When people use `git merge` to combine work, that leaves the original commits undisturbed.  That way, if someone else—like you!—are using those original commits in some way, Git knows those commits are properly incorporated, because each merge records *both* parents of the merge operation.  The graph—the connecting lines going from later commits back to earlier ones—shows the true history of commits and development, and Git can figure everything out.

When people use `git rebase` to combine work, they *discard* their original commits in favor of new and (supposedly) improved *copies* of the original commits.  If everyone else knows to deal with this problem right away, everyone else who's sharing work with this repository can handle this before it becomes a huge mess.  Or, if no one else has ever seen these commits, you—the person doing this `git rebase` right now—can be sure that *no* one else is using your originals.  When you abandon them in favor of new and improved commits, you are not stranding someone else who's using your commits, because no one else *has* your commits.

But in this case, you've been stranded: you were using someone else's commits, then *they* ripped them out (in favor of new-and-improved rebased commits), and they thought everyone was done with them.  But you were and are still using them and now Git thinks these are *your* commits and is dragging them around with you wherever you go.  Now, after all this time, *now* you have to rid yourself of these commits, and the only way you can do that is by *selective* copying.

Comment: this should be an accepted answer, great description btw!